# New to C: Storing Structures in an Array

Tags: c, arrays, structure

My first C assignment is to create a Queue. I am using an array based implementation as opposed to a linked list.

I am getting the following error when I try to compile my code:

```
Queue.c: In function 'Enqueue':
Queue.c:23: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
```

Here is my code, I will supply the header code if needed:

```
#include "QueueElement.h"
#include "Queue.h"

#define QUEUE_SIZE 10

struct QueueStruct {
        QueueElement *contents[QUEUE_SIZE];
        int size;
};

Queue CreateQueue(void) {
        Queue q = malloc(sizeof(struct QueueStruct));
        q->size = 0;
        return q;
}

void DestroyQueue(Queue q) {
        free(q);
}

void Enqueue(Queue q, QueueElement *e) {
        if (q->size < QUEUE_SIZE) {

                q->contents[q->size++] = *e;        /* PROBLEM IS HERE */

        }
}
```

Any help with this problem is greatly appreciated as well as any other suggestions.
Thanks guys.

Comment: It seems like esoteric pointer notation usage. You're trying to derreference e, thus copying the value of e (which is a contiguous block of memory of almost any size) into a pointer (which is usually 4 bytes). Things don't fit and even if the sizes matched, `QueueElement` is not the same as `QueueElement*`.

Comment: What's `Queue`? There's no definition of `Queue` in the code you provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe `q->contents[q->size++] = *e;` should simply be `q->contents[q->size++] = e;`.

The `*` dereferences the pointer to the actual value at the memory location and I don't think you want that--you want the pointer.

Comment: That was it. The program compiles now. Thanks again for the quick responses guys. (waiting to mark as answered)

Comment: Great! As a follow up, I found that this guide was immensely useful to me for learning pointers in C: http://pw1.netcom.com/~tjensen/ptr/pointers.htm . It is 50 pages long and teaches you the basics of how pointers, referencing, dereferencing and arrays work in C. It a very worthwhile read.

Answer (score 4):

I believe you mean

```
q->contents[q->size++] = e;
```

(Without the asterisks)
because you're assigning something of type QueueElement* to an array of QueueElement*[].

or you might be able to fix it by changing this instead - which might be closer to what I figure you might mean:-

```
QueueElement contents[QUEUE_SIZE];
```

Not sure if this makes sense/I'm right at all.

Answer (score 2):

`*e` is of type `QueueElement` and `q->contents[q->size++]` is a `QueueElement*`

You should either drop the `*` before e or declare the contents as:

```
    QueueElement contents[QUEUE_SIZE];
```

It depends if you are trying to store pointers or values.